# When i run appium script then through error as per below

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, mobile, automation, appium

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<init>(java.net.URI, java.time.Duration, java.time.Duration, org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter, java.net.Proxy, org.openqa.selenium.Credentials)'
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.<init>(AppiumClientConfig.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.defaultConfig(AppiumClientConfig.java:79)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:101)
    at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:104)
    at Appiumbase.BaseIOSTest.main(BaseIOSTest.java:61)
```

Answer (score -1):

Update the appium java-client version to 8.6.0. It worked for me in IntelliJ. I am using Appium2 and Java 17.